# Skeleton unit test for leetcode coding problems

Tags: python, unit-testing

I tried to initiate myself with unit testing the simplest way I can. What do you think of this way to begin with? Is it a clean way to proceed? Are there any major caveats to avoid?

NB:

- Since I want to test a small script for each leetcode problem, I preferred to have the `Test` inside the script to be tested (and not in a different file).
- I decided to use `f` as a global variable inside the main scope (I could have defined it in `Test` as a class variable and use `self.f`).
- I create a function test for each case.

```
import unittest

class Solution(object):
    def islandPerimeter(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    f = Solution().islandPerimeter

    class Test(unittest.TestCase):
        
        def test_multiple_path(self):    
            self.assertEqual(f( [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]), 16)
         
        def test_one_square(self):
            self.assertEqual(f( [[1]]), 4)

    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I recommend putting unit tests in a separate package called `tests` in your project's root. This way, tools like `pytest` will automagically find and run appropriate tests.

Comment: For simple tests like this, consider using `doctest` to embed the tests within the function's docstring.